# What is the difference in running integration tests with flutter drive/test/run?

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

I'm having an issue with the integration tests in my app, for which if I run them in **profile mode** with `flutter drive` some tests get stuck in a given section of the app instead of starting from the first screen.

This is not happening if I run the tests with `flutter test` or with `flutter drive` in *debug mode*. Also, the issue disappears if I run the tests with `flutter run` in *profile mode*.

What is the difference between running integration tests with the different commands? I'm thinking about Exception management, but it could also be something I'm not aware about.